# AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this) - Crashes App

Tags: java, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to use the Facebook SDK to track my installs. I've imported the Facebook SDK into my workspace using Eclipse but for some reason when I have this code in my .java file my app will not start: `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);` -- It will show the message that my app has stopped.

Should I be configuring something correctly in my Java Build Path or Android Library? Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application .........
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</application>
```

and this line to your stings.xml

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">your app id here</string>
```

thats all. good luck